# Many to many relationship with nested forms in Rails 4 - Unpermitted parameters error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to make the relationship in the Products controller through the Categorizations model to the ClothingSize model. I am getting a "Unpermitted parameters: clothing_size" error and the relationship is not ever made as a result. I think there is something wrong with the nested forms in the view as I cannot get the "Size" field to appear unless the symbol is singular shown below. I think that may be pointing to another problem.

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :clothing_size do |cs| %>
```

Models

Products

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :clothing_sizes, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end
```

Categorizations

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :clothing_size
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clothing_size
end
```

ClothingSizes

```
class ClothingSize < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end
```

Controller for Products

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  test = @product.categorizations.build


  def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :image_url2, :price, :quantity, :color, :clothing_sizes => [:sizes, :clothing_size_id])
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :clothing_size do |cs| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= cs.label :sizes, "Sizes" %><br>
      <%= cs.text_field :sizes  %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view you have `:clothing_size` (singular) but in your `product_params` method you have `:clothing_sizes` (plural). Because your `Product` model `has_many :clothing_sizes`, you want it to be plural in your view.

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :clothing_sizes do |cs| %>
```

In addition, you'll want to build a `clothing_size` for your `product` in your controller, and permit `:clothing_sizes_attributes` rather than `clothing` sizes in your `product_params` method. (I'd separate your `new` and `product_params` methods, making `product_params` private, but that's just me.)

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @clothing_size = @product.clothing_sizes.build
end

private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :image_url2, :price, :quantity, :color, :clothing_sizes_attributes => [:sizes, :clothing_size_id])
  end
```

Comment: When I make clothing_size plural in the view the field does not show up at all on the page. I'm not sure why. That's why it's singular. There must be something else wrong that's causing this behavior.

Comment: It should be plural, because the relationship is plural. The reason nothing is showing up is because you need to build at least one `clothing_size` for your `@product`. You can add this in your controller: `@product.clothing_sizes.build`.

Comment: That seems to have moved me one step further. The size is now showing up on the form. I am now getting this error: `Unpermitted parameters: clothing_sizes_attributes`

Comment: Ah right, you'll need to switch `:clothing_sizes` to `:clothing_sizes_attributes` in your `product_params` method, since you're using nested attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Highly appreciated. The categorization model is successfully creating the row. I'm going to do some research on _attributes now.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear. Check out the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), specifically the [Form Helpers guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) for more info on nested attributes and forms.